# Flask query join

Tags: python, flask, inner-join, flask-sqlalchemy

I have database with two tables:

```
class Meals(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'meals'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    description = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    picture = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    category = db.relationship("Category")
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))



class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    meals = db.relationship("Meals", back_populates='category')
```

I want to get query containing Meals.title and Category.title

For example:
Meals table

```
Burger_Grand_Canyon  1
Fresh_roll_with_chicken 1
Pizza_Margarita_classic 2
```

Category Table

```
Burgers 1
Pizzas 2
```

As result

```
Burger_Grand_Canyon  Burgers
Fresh_roll_with_chicken Burgers
Pizza_Margarita_classic Pizzas
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
dishes = db.session.query(Meals).join(Category).all()
print(dishes)
for dish in dishes:
    print(dish.title)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It's worth including the error or unexpected result you got from your final example. Right now, it's not clear what the result of your code is, to help illustrate precisely where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your query should give you a list of `Dish` records assigned to the `dishes` variable. Each instance of `Dish` should be able to reference its linked `Category` instance via the `dish.category` field.

In other words, it should be something more like this:

```
dishes = db.session.query(Meals).join(Category).all()
for dish in dishes:
    print(dish.title, dish.category.title)
```